# icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts not working for broadcast other than 255

Tags: linux-networking, icmp

In an embedded system using linux 5.3.18 it is required to ignore ICMP broadcasts. This device IP set to `192.168.0.34/25`, so the broadcast will be `192.168.0.127`. The flag controlling this behaviour `icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts` is correclty set to `1`

When an ICMP echo request with source IP `192.168.0.127` is sent, I would expect this request to be ignored since a response would be a broadcast, but the response is present and the dst MAC is now `ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`

If the mask is set to `/24` this works as intended.
Is my undestanding of calculated broadcast incorrect?
Why was the dst MAC address changed?

Comment: You set the source IP to the broadcast address!?

Comment: Not sure if I undestand you, I've modified the question. The device has IP `192.168.0.34/25`. The source address of the ICMP pkg it is the broadcast address.

Comment: Broadcast and multicast addresses are not allowed to be source addresses. You broke that rule, so the reply will be back to the broadcast address as the reply destination (original source) address, both at layer-2 (MAC) and layer-3 (IP). You host implementations are flawed to allow and accept a source broadcast address.

Answer (score 3):

ICMP echoes don't have a source address as a broadcast. The source is the unicast address of the source. The destination will be a the broadcast address.

Comment: Then the test method is incorrect? If so, then the response to the ip dst `192.168.0.127` is not a broadcast?

Comment: No the response destination is the unicast source

Comment: any clue why the MAC address was changed to `ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`?

Comment: Because you set the source to the broadcast address.  It's an invalid packet that you would never see on your network.